# Getting error while switching from Android studio 2.1 to 2.2

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

I have updated my android studio 1.1 Preview 5 with Android studo 2.2.
When i open or create project is always gives an error like

> Cannot load project: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.debugger.DebuggerManager'

[image]

I have tried to load my previous android studio's configurations but still it gives an error.
Then i have started without importing configuration and it also gives an error.

I have tried to remove cache directory and then also gives an error.

So please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem I tried to download and reinstall the Android Studio
but the error appeared again on the second start of the app.

Finally I found that my desktop shortcut had a wrong target file **studio.exe**, not **studio64.exe**.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a couple weeks figuring this one out but as it turns out the issue was with my Java Home environment variable.  I had mistakenly set jre1.8.etc as my home when it in fact needed to be the jdk1.8.0_101.

I probably just clicked on the wrong dl link because when I redownloaded the jdk it replaced the jre file. Hope this helps.